# How to map ggplot stat_sum to size aesthetics?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

In my understanding ggplot's stat methods take arrays of values and calculate new values which can be displayed by certain aesthetics. I would like the size of the points to be proportional with the sum of a numeric variable within each group (unique `x, y` combinations). I was surprised that whenever there were more than one values in one group multiple points have been plotted instead of one point representing the sum of all. Here is a minimal working example:

```
ex_data <- data.frame(
    a = sort(rep(letters[1:4], 5)),
    b = rep(letters[6:7], 10),
    c = rnorm(20, 1000, 500),
    d = rep(c('h', 'h', 'i', 'i'), 5)
)

p <- ggplot(ex_data,
    aes(x = b, y = a, size = log10(c), color = d, shape = d)) +
    geom_point(stat = 'sum', alpha = 0.33) +
    scale_radius(guide = guide_legend(title = 'c (log)')) +
    scale_color_manual(values = c('cyan', 'magenta'),
                    guide = guide_legend(title = 'd'),
                    labels = c('h', 'i')) +
    scale_shape_manual(values = c(15, 18), guide = FALSE) +
    theme_bw()

print(p)
```

Thanks to low alpha it is visible that for example at `c-f` and `a-f` multiple points of the same color are plotted over each other. How I could achieve to have one point for each color at each location and the size of these marks represent the sum of all values of `log10(c)` variable within that group?

Comment: How can there be one point if you are mapping two colors on that coordinate? What color should that point have? And what shape?

Comment: I mean one point for each color, but not 2 points of the same color at the same location

Comment: In general, I find `stat_summary` useful for simply summary functions on the `y` aesthetic.  It sounds like you want to summarize the dataset down to a single value of `c` for each `a`/`b`/`d` combination.  This is likely most straightforward to do that outside of ggplot, using the summarized dataset to create the desired plot.

Comment: that's right, but why is this limitation, why only `y` aesthetic? and why there is no error or warning message, just silently doesn't do its job? also `geom_count` does this properly with count statistics, it would be nice to be able to use any other statistics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `stat='sum'` is able to work together only with `y` aesthetics, hence we need to aggregate the data and apply statistics before going to `ggplot`. Here is a working example with `dplyr`. *(Note: Stack Overflow reviewers did not allow me to edit MAK77's reply and accept it, that's the only reason I am writing a new answer.)*

```
require(dplyr)
require(ggplot2)

ex_data <- data.frame(
    a = sort(rep(letters[1:4], 5)),
    b = rep(letters[6:7], 10),
    c = rnorm(20, 1000, 500),
    d = rep(c('h', 'h', 'i', 'i'), 5)
)

ex_data_2 <- ex_data %>%
        group_by(a, b, d) %>%
        mutate(csum = sum(c)) %>%
        summarise_all(first)

p <- ggplot(ex_data_2,
            aes(x = b, y = a, size = log(csum), color = d, shape = d)) +
    geom_point(alpha = 0.33) +
    scale_radius(guide = guide_legend(title = 'c (log)')) +
    scale_color_manual(values = c('cyan', 'magenta'),
                    guide = guide_legend(title = 'd'),
                    labels = c('h', 'i')) +
    scale_shape_manual(values = c(15, 18), guide = FALSE) + 
    theme_bw()
p
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to reshape the data somehow. Here is my example (with `data.table` and `dplyr`)

```
ex_data_2 <- data.table(ex_data) %>%
    .[, list(c = sum(c), 
             d = which.max(table(d))), by = list(a, b)] %>%
    .[, d := c('c', 'd')[d]]
p <- ggplot(ex_data_2,
            aes(x = b, y = a, size = log(c), color = d, shape = d)) +
    geom_point(stat = 'sum', alpha = 0.33) +
    scale_radius(guide = guide_legend(title = 'c (log)')) +
    scale_color_manual(values = c('cyan', 'magenta'),
                       guide = guide_legend(title = 'd'),
                       labels = c('h', 'i')) +
    scale_shape_manual(values = c(15, 18), guide = FALSE) + 
    theme_bw()
p
```

Comment: `Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
Have you called 'sort' on a list?`

Comment: thanks for the answer! I run the code and this drops one level of `d` at each point, so I have either cyan or magenta (I guess due to `which_max(table(d))`. other thing is that this way the `stat` does not make sense, enough to pass `size` to the main aesthetics, so this convenience of ggplot can not be exploited.